# Accessing bean attributes from jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2

Let's say I have a bean with a boolean attribute called display. Is there any way I can access the value of that attribute from jquery? Something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if(bean.display){
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of this question, JSF is merely a HTML/CSS/JS code producer. Just let JSF print a bean property as if it's part of JS code. Just make use EL the usual way.

```html
<h:outputScript>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        if(#{bean.display}){
           doSomething();
        }
    }
</h:outputScript>
```

Open JSF page in webbrowser, rightclick and *View Source* to see the generated HTML output. It should look something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        if(true){
           doSomething();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note that if JSF did its job of generating the HTML output right, you should not see any Java/JSF/EL code in the HTML output. You just have to write Java/JSF/EL code in such way that it produces exactly the desired HTML/CSS/JS code.

---

Or, if that script is actually enclosed in a JS file, let JSF print it as a JS variable:

```
<h:outputScript name="some.js" />
<h:outputScript>var display = #{bean.display};</h:outputScript>
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if(display){
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

---

Or, if you absolutely want to keep your initial `bean.display` JS object syntax, do so:

```
<h:outputScript name="some.js" />
<h:outputScript>var bean = { display: #{bean.display} };</h:outputScript>
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if(bean.display){
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can store it inside some `outputText` or `inputText`

For example:

```
<h:outputText id="my_display" value="#{myBean.display}" style="display:none"/>
```

and use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($("#my_display").text() === "someValue"){
       doSomething();
    }
}
```